# Quarkus job scheduler

Tags: java, jobs, quarkus, java-ee-6, schedule

So I am using ManagedScheduledExecutorService in a Java EE project that I am migrating to Quarkus, like so:

```
@Resource
private ManagedScheduledExecutorService scheduler;
```

The only thing I need from this dependency is to be able to schedule a command, by invoking the `shedule` function:

```
this.scheduler.schedule(this::refreshToken, TENTATIVE_LOGIN_IN_SECONDS, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Is there any way I can achieve this in Quarkus?

Comment: If you want a task to run in the background after a delay then check out this article https://quarkus.io/guides/reactive-event-bus. I haven't tested it, but reading through it it seems to me like you could use the Vert.x `EventBus` to fire-and-forget an event which the consumer could delay then run.

Comment: Did you had a chance to review documentation https://quarkus.io/guides/scheduler#standard-scheduling. I believe this example would help in your context.